# how to check the classname and remove it in the html list?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   <ul id="freelancer">
     <li class="item active">Name</li>
     <li class="item">Skills</li>
     <li class="item">Cost</li>
     <li class="item active">Projects</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so here there are 2 li where the active class is available.
i want to find the active class in the list and remove the classname from there.
i tried the below example to check whether i will get the value. but it is only checking for the first li that appears. its not looping on the li's and checking.

```
const div = document.querySelector('li');
console.log(div.classList.contains('active'));
```

what is the other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `querySelector` to [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Also use the query as `querySelectorAll(li.active)`, so that you will get all the active class in the li.

Then iterate it and remove the class using [classList.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) like `item.classList.remove('active')`

```js
const activeClasses = document.querySelectorAll('li.active');

activeClasses.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('active'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   <ul id="freelancer">
     <li class="item active">Name</li>
     <li class="item">Skills</li>
     <li class="item">Cost</li>
     <li class="item active">Projects</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` only return first match.

If you want all matches, use `querySelectorAll()` instead:

```
const activeLi = querySelectorAll('li.active')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use querySelectorAll(),
And use classList.Remove("ClassName);

Here is a working exemple :

```js
function removeActive(){

  var activeItems = document.querySelectorAll('li.active');
 
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(activeItems, function(item) {
   
     item.classList.remove("active");
     
  });
 
}
```

```css
.active{
color:red;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
   <ul id="freelancer">
     <li class="item active">Name</li>
     <li class="item">Skills</li>
     <li class="item">Cost</li>
     <li class="item active">Projects</li>
   </ul>
   
   <button onclick="removeActive();">Remove active class</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```